# Polymer paper-drawer-panel not accepting toggle from child

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I have a `paper-drawer-panel` in one element and a toolbar in a child element. On the toolbar is a menu-button, that should toggle the drawer-panel but it does not. How can I tell the `paper-drawer-panel` to accept a command from the child element?

Parent-element:

```
<dom-module id="nav-drawer">
<template>
   <paper-drawer-panel drawerFocusSelector="">
      <div drawer id="drawerbox">
         Contents of drawer panel here.
      </div>
      <div main>
         <tool-bar></tool-bar>
      </div>
   <paper-drawer-panel>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

Child element:

```
<dom-module id="tool-bar">
  <template>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-toolbar>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Thanks for your help. I'm new to Polymer.

Comment: The above solution only works to open the drawer panel. When opened, in my view it overlays the menu button so closing is just by clicking next to it. If you want to close it via the menu button too, you need to make sure it passes `togdraw:"main"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:
The `tool-bar` element I changed as follows, adding `attributes` and an `on-tap` function.

```
<dom-module id="tool-bar" attributes="togdraw">
  <template>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="toggleDrawer"></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-toolbar>
  </template>
<script>
.....
      toggleDrawer: function() {
        this.fire('eventFromChild',{togdraw:"drawer"});
      }
....
</script>

</dom-module>
```

And the `nav-drawer` I changed like accordingly:

```
<dom-module id="nav-drawer">
<template>
   <paper-drawer-panel drawerFocusSelector="" selected="{{selectPanel}}">
      <div drawer id="drawerbox">
         Contents of drawer panel here.
      </div>
      <div main>
         <tool-bar></tool-bar>
      </div>
   <paper-drawer-panel>
</template>
<script>
....
  properties: {
      selectPanel: String
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.addEventListener('eventFromChild', this.toggleDrawer);
  },
  toggleDrawer: function(event,selectPanel) {
    this.selectPanel = event.detail.togdraw;
    return selectPanel;
  }
....
</script>
</dom-module>
```